# Reading array in a loop and ignoring spaces in favor of a newline

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I am trying to load a variable '$LIST' that contains an array using the 'for' loop. However, I don't want them to be separated at spaces, but at the point of a new line.
How can I get this effect?

```
LIST=( \
"1" "Some text" "ON" \
"2" "Some text" "OFF" \
"3" "Some text. Some text" "ON" \
"4" "Some text" "OFF" \
"5" "Some text. Some text" "OFF" \
)

for ENTRY in "${LIST[@]}"
do
    echo "$ENTRY"
done
```

I currently gets the following result:

```
1
Some text
ON
2
Some text
OFF
3
Some text. Some text
ON
4
Some text
OFF
5
Some text. Some text
OFF
```

And I would like to get this:

```
1 Some text ON
2 Some text OFF
3 Some text. Some text ON
4 Some text OFF
5 Some text. Some text OFF
```

Comment: You want to group your array by 3 elements each. I would therefore use a counting loop and in each iteration print 3 elements in one row.

Comment: Alternatively, you can keep a running counter during the loop and use `echo -n` instead of plain `echo` (and thereby suppressing the newline), but on every 3rd iteration just print a sole newline.

Comment: Is it always 3 elements per line? Some of the answers make that assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need to use line continuation back-slashes `\` to arrange the declaration of your list array.

Next, non exported variables are best entirely lower-case.

To iterate your list/array by groups of 3 element; passing the array elements as arguments to a function allows to do what you want.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

list=(
  "1" "Some text" "ON"
  "2" "Some text" "OFF"
  "3" "Some text. Some text" "ON"
  "4" "Some text" "OFF"
  "5" "Some text. Some text" "OFF"
)

do_output () {
  # iterates while there are still arguments
  while [ $# -gt 0 ]
  do
    # prints 3 arguments
    printf '%s %s %s\n' "$1" "$2" "$3"
    # shifts to the next 3 arguments
    shift 3
  done
}

do_output "${list[@]}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `printf`:

```bash
$ printf '%s %s %s\n' "${LIST[@]}"
1 Some text ON
2 Some text OFF
3 Some text. Some text ON
4 Some text OFF
5 Some text. Some text OFF
```

`printf` iterates as long as all arguments have not been consumed.

Answer (score 0):

Put each line in quotes, not each word. You can add double quotes around the string of multiple words that should be the description.

```
LIST=( 
'1 "Some text" ON' 
'2 "Some text" OFF'
'3 "Some text. Some text" ON' 
'4 "Some text" OFF' 
'5 "Some text. Some text" OFF' 
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that.

Comment: Why can't you do that? How are you really creating the array?

Comment: I want to use an array to create a menu (whiptail --checklist). Each item contains three items. One of them is a description that must be enclosed in "" :)

Comment: I've updated the answer to add quotes around the description.